# Installing UltraVNC over msi, but only the viewer

Tags: windows, windows-installer, ultravnc

I got the UltraVNC `.msi` file to install it to a machine using powershell. I can install it without issues using:

```
Start-Process 'msiexec' -ArgumentList '/i "PATH_TO_FILE.msi" /qn /norestart'
```

But this only installs the server. Is there any way for me to not install the server, but only the client?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to install it automatically:

1. Use the `.exe` instead of `.msi`
2. Run it using like this: `setup.exe /safeinf="C:\path\file.inf"`
3. Go through the window once, which gives you your `.inf` file
4. Now you can run it automated using `setup.exe /loadinf='file.inf' /verysilent`

Answer (score 0):

The interactive
[Installation](https://uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-server/48-uvnc-server-installation.html)
of UltraVNC allows three types of installations:

- Full installation
- UltraVNC Server Only
- UltraVNC Server Only"silent"
- UltraVNC Viewer Only

Your method of installation doesn't let you choose the Viewer only,
so it installs according to some defaults.
If you're only interested in the Viewer, I suggest to run the
setup interactively.